# Workarounds to import java lib for mingw / ios / linus / other source sets?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am aware that it's quite a weird use case to depend on having JVM installed for some OS source sets, allow me to go through my use case.

I'm writing a simple utility to wrap calls for the steamCMD (https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD), which has platform dependent installation procedures. So, naturally I should have

```
// commonMain / steamCmdGetter.kt
expect interface SteamCmdGetter {
    fun installClient()
}
// [OS] / steamCmdGetter.kt
actual interface SteamCmdGetter { /* ... */ }
```

On the other hand, my utility also needs to do work with the file storage (for example, downloading and checking client existence in storage), so I could also use a file class.

```
// commonMain / File.kt
expect interface File
```

I am aware that the JB team has an explicit recommendation on its tutorials.

> We recommend that you use expected and actual declarations only for Kotlin declarations that have platform-specific dependencies. It is better to implement as much functionality as possible in the shared module even if doing so takes more time.

Yet, against the warnings I wish not to write a `MyFile` implementation to save efforts from reinventing the wheel for such a common task, but `java.io.File` has been so dominant in the scene that I could not find any Kotlin alternatives on Gradle / Maven.

Does this means I am forced to write `MyFile` in the end? Or is there a workaround for importing Java libraries to Kotlin MPP platform sourceSets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, one can use Java libraries only for `jvm` and `android` targets, not the others provided by the Kotlin/Multiplatform. In fact, this is exactly a targets subset that is using Kotlin/JVM. Neither Kotlin/JS nor Kotlin/Native provide interoperability with Java, they has their own interop capabilities. See [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) to get some details on the difference.
 About working with files in particular. Most probably the answer is yes and you'll have to implement it per-target. This kind of work is usually platform-specific, as it hardly rely on the OS implementation. However, part of the functionality you search for should be definitely found in the `platform.posix.*` [platform library](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/platform_libs.html), even if it would appear more C-stylish.

---

P.S. Quick search across the Web led me to this community libraries [list](https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries#file), maybe it would help. Also, kotlinlang Slack community(find link [here](https://kotlinlang.org/community/)) may have some interesting solutions to share.